# Checking Session - php not printing

Tags: php

```
<?php session_start();
$_SESSION['loggedIn'] = "no";
echo "Logged In: ". $_SESSION['loggedIn'];

if($_SESSION['loggedIn']=="yes"): 
    echo "logged in";
}
else{
    echo "not logged in";
}
?>
```

I am simply trying to check if the session "loggedIn" is yes or no, but the program doesn't print anything.

Why does it not print anything?

Comment: Have you got error reporting turned on?

Comment: no. i don't know how to do that

Comment: You have a syntax error. Remove the colon `:` after the `if` statement and replace it with `{`

Comment: and turn on error reporting during development.  `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Better `error_reporting(~0);` or (equally) `error_reporting(-1);` instead of `E_ALL` for development.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using alternative if/then as well as regular syntax.

```
if($_SESSION['loggedIn']=="yes"):
```

should be

```
if($_SESSION['loggedIn']=="yes"){
    echo "logged in";
}
else{
    echo "not logged in";
}
```

its a simple syntax error

Answer (score 2):

Remove `:` after `if` and place `{`

Change

```
if($_SESSION['loggedIn']=="yes"):
```

To

```
if($_SESSION['loggedIn']=="yes") {
```

Answer (score 1):

You've used a colon to open an if:

```
if($_SESSION['loggedIn']=="yes"):
```

Change it to a `{`

```
if($_SESSION['loggedIn']=="yes"){
```

It is valid syntax to open an if with `:` but you must close it with `endif;` instead of `}`.

Example of the alternate syntax:

```
if($_SESSION['loggedIn']=="yes"):
    echo "logged in";
else:
    echo "not logged in";
endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

either remove the `:` or use the alternative syntax  [php alternative syntax for control structures](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)

either:

```
if($_SESSION['loggedIn']=="yes"){
    echo "logged in";
}
else{
    echo "not logged in";
}
```

or:

```
if($_SESSION['loggedIn']=="yes"):
    echo "logged in";    
else:
    echo "not logged in";
endif;
```